# Custom cordova plugin - Get path to file

Tags: android, cordova, path, cordova-plugins, filepath

I've created a Cordova plugin for Android, and I've put a file in the `src` folder:

**Plugin.xml**

```
<source-file src="myfile.ext" target-dir="src/com/example"/>
```

I also can see (in Android Studio) that the file was succesfully added in the `src` folder:

```
android
 |-- /src
      |-- com
           |-- example
                |-- myfile.ext
                |-- MyPlugin.java
```

Now I need to be able to get the path to this file in **MyPlugin.java**, but I've no clue how to do this. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you updated your question, it was correct - you should copy the asset file to "assets" not "src":

```
<source-file src="myfile.ext" target-dir="assets"/>
```

Then you can reference it via the [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html):

```
AssetManager assetManager = this.cordova.getActivity().getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("myfile.ext");
```

In terms of "path" to the file, assets are stored in the APK differently from how your Android project is constructed, so the "path" to your file would be `file:///android_asset/myfile.ext`, but you most likely wouldn't actually be referencing it like this from `MyPlugin.java`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DaveAlden, I really need to get the "path" because I need that as input for an API call. Anyway, it's not working unfortunately.. when I try `new File("file:///android_asset/myfile.ext").exists()` it returns `false`. Also doing `new File("file:///android_asset/").exists()` returns `false`. Any idea why?
(I added the file back under `assets` folder)

Comment: `File file = new File("//android_asset/myfile.ext"); Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);`

Comment: Still no luck, the `uri` is exactly the same as `file:///android_asset/myfile.ext` and will return `false` when trying to do `new File(uri.toString).exists()`. Reason I make a `new File()` and check if it exists is because the API will do that also. Other suggestions?
Reason I editted my original post to maybe place the file in the same folder (src) as the java file was so it could potentionally be easier to get the path. If that's possible/easier, what would the path be?

Comment: You need check where the API you are using expects the file to be located and what syntax the input path should be. In my plugins I use `AssetManager` for all asset file access. Assets are not unpacked from the APK, so are not available via the File API.

Comment: It's this API, https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/blob/master/tess-two/src/com/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI.java, when trying to call the `init` method (line 299), it returns `"Data path does not exist!"`. I don't think it expects a specific location, as long as it exists.

Comment: Then I would still bundle the file as an asset within the APK, but copy it out of the APK to sdcard at runtime, making it accessible as a file - see [How to copy files from 'assets' folder to sdcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/how-to-copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sdcard). Once it's a file on the SD card, you can get its absolute path.

Comment: Thanks, I copied it to sdcard and I can use it. I will accept this as the answer since now I can continue.